# Lua - Sum a table that may have nil values

Tags: lua

I am looking to sum a table in lua but having problems if my table contains any nil values. A user is filling out a form to provide my table values so they could leave a field in the table blank.

How can I handle the nil values? I would want nil to = 0 when summing.

```
for key,value in pairs(contsum_data) do

  chars ={',','%','$','₠','₡','₢','₣','₤','₥','₦','₧','₨','₩','₪','₫','€','₭','₮','₯','₱','₲','₳','₴','₵','₶','₷','₸','₹'}

  val = str_replace(chars, '', value)  
  
  finalval = finalval + val
end
```

Comment: I answered your question based on the information given. if that is not what you wanted to know you should reword your post so it makes more sense. provide example input for contsum_data, provide str_replace and finalval

Comment: Try `finalval = finalval + (tonumber(val) or 0)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff this small change worked! Thanks very much for the help. New to Lua and trying to pick it up as I go, so apologies for the poorly worded question.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff could you post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `finalval = finalval + (tonumber(val) or 0)`

Explanation:

1. `val` is a string, so you have to convert it to number before applying arithmetic
2. If `val` is not a valid string literal (for example, it might be an empty string), `tonumber` returns `nil`
3. To convert `nil` to zero, "short-circuit OR" operator is used: `x = x or 0`

Answer (score 1):

Your request has two flaws.

a) a Lua table has an infinite number of nil values

b) adding 0 does not change a number.

So you're asking for a solution on how to do nothing to a value infinite times.

The answer is pretty simple. You just don't do anything and leave the value unchanged. Add the values you have and don't care about nil values.

Answer (score 0):

`pairs` only iterates over non-nil values.

consider this code:

```
data = {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = nil,
    d = 4
}
for key,value in pairs(data) do
    print(key, value)
end
```

in the for loop it won't even take the key `c`. so this loop iterates 3 times.

Same when defining the table as a list like

```
data = {1 ,2 , nil, 4}
```

for example.

So I think your issue isn't having nil values. Possibly the error lies with input that are not numbers. I also don't know what the implementation of `str_replace` is so the problem might be there